# Gazebo crashes when spawning robot from URDF

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When launching `pioneer3dx.gazebo.launch` from the [p2os_urdf](http://wiki.ros.org/p2os_urdf?distro=groovy) ROS package, gazebo crashes with the following error message:

```
[INFO] [1491870638.263414, 0.215000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1491870638.489795, 0.361000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned model
[spawn_pioneer-5] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/damjan/.ros/log/149f697e-1e4e-11e7-833b-3c970e29894f/spawn_pioneer-5*.log
Error [Param.cc:451] Unable to set value [-nan -nan -nan] for key[size]
gzclient: /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:630: virtual void Ogre::Node::setScale(const Ogre::Vector3&): Assertion `!inScale.isNaN() && "Invalid vector supplied as parameter"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-4] process has died [pid 26353, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/damjan/.ros/log/149f697e-1e4e-11e7-833b-3c970e29894f/gazebo_gui-4.log]
```

I'm running ROS Kinetic with Gazebo 7 (both installed with `apt`) on Xenial.

Seems to be a different issue from [this one](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6360/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-a-robot-with-urdf/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15816/gazebo-crashes-when-spawning-robot-from-urdf/) by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had the same issue.
Sensor collistions are broken in the model. In amr_robots_description/urdf open all xacro files and replace size="0 0 0" with something like size="0.01 0.01 0.01". Then It'll work

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on 2017-04-16**:
Thanks, this solved the crash!

**Comment by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
please note there are two pull request into amr to fix this bug, as well as some others.

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3087/damjan/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thanks! For now, I have ported your changes to [my p2os fork](https://github.com/larics/p2os/tree/bugfix-urdf-p3dx/p2os_urdf). Right now amr-ros-config seems a bit unwieldy due to all the stuff that's in there.

**Comment by [midoosman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22727/midoosman/) on 2020-12-14**:
worked for me, Thanks